# Multiple, flexible logical column comparison in Data.table

Tags: r, boolean, data.table, logic

I want to compare multiple columns in a data table in R, and I do not want to hardcode them.  For example, see the simple example below:

```
###########
#Setup data
###########

set.seed(2)
fill = data.table(n=1:7)
Tp=3

for(t in 1:Tp){ 
  set(x = fill, j = paste0('v',t), value = sample(0:10,7))
}

fill[1,paste0('v',3):=0]
fill[5,paste0('v',2):=0]
fill[5,paste0('v',3):=0]

for(t in 1:Tp){ 
  fill[,paste0('v',t,'prm'):=get(paste0('v',t))]
}

fill[1,paste0('v',1,'prm'):=0] 
fill[2,paste0('v',2,'prm'):=1]   
fill[5,paste0('v',3,'prm'):=1]  
fill[7,paste0('v',3,'prm'):=2]
```

So the data is:

```
> fill
   n v1 v2 v3 v1prm v2prm v3prm
1: 1  2  9  0     0     9     0
2: 2  7  4  8     7     1     8
3: 3  5 10  9     5    10     9
4: 4  1  8  1     1     8     1
5: 5  6  0  0     6     0     1
6: 6  8  7  0     8     7     0
7: 7  0  0  6     0     0     2
```

And I want to compare numberwise each column with its 'prm', as follows:

```
fill[v1==v1prm & v2==v2prm & v3==v3prm]
```

So the output is:

```
> fill[v1==v1prm & v2==v2prm & v3==v3prm]

   n v1 v2 v3 v1prm v2prm v3prm
1: 3  5 10  9     5    10     9
2: 4  1  8  1     1     8     1
3: 6  8  7  0     8     7     0
```

But I do not want to hardcode this because I might use more than 3 columns.  Also, I may want to use other comparison, such as...

```
> fill[v1>v1prm & v2==v2prm & v3==v3prm]

   n v1 v2 v3 v1prm v2prm v3prm
1: 1  2  9  0     0     9     0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a functional approach here via `Map`:

```
## set some variable names
pre <- paste0("v", 1:3)
pst <- paste0(pre, "prm")

## select where they match using `==` and Reduce to combine with a `&` (logical AND)
fill[Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, mget(pre), mget(pst)))]
#   n v1 v2 v3 v1prm v2prm v3prm
#1: 3  5 10  9     5    10     9
#2: 4  1  8  1     1     8     1
#3: 6  8  7  0     8     7     0
```

Extending this logic to loop over different logical comparisons:

```
funs <- c(`>`, `==`, `==`)
fill[Reduce(`&`, Map(function(pr,ps,f) f(pr,ps), mget(pre), mget(pst), funs))]
#   n v1 v2 v3 v1prm v2prm v3prm
#1: 1  2  9  0     0     9     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Functional approach answer is cool, but I prefer the pedestrian `eval/parse` instead here since it's easier to read/maintain:

```
lhs = paste0('v', 1:3)
fns = c('>', '==', '==')
rhs = paste0(pre, 'prm')

fill[eval(parse(text = paste(lhs, fns, rhs, collapse = '&')))]
#   n v1 v2 v3 v1prm v2prm v3prm
#1: 1  2  9  0     0     9     0
```